# How to center text in android screen (not center in parent)

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to center a small text in center of screen based on the default "Empty activity" as per code samples in Android Studio 2.1.

The layout xml file i use today is as provided below. I inflate it in the `OnCreate` method as normal through the `setContentView`, so the layout as defined in the xml dont fill the whole screen. Thus the `layout_centerInParent` will center my texts in the parent, but not center in screen.  How do i get my text to center on screen, while keeping my action bar?

**Illustration of problem**
Centering in parent leads to "bad" position. Centering on screen would give "good" postion.

[image: The problem. Centering in parent leads to "bad" position. Centering on screen would give "good" postion.]

**main_activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.sara.internetcheck.MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_header"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/good_news_title" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_body"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/text_header"
            android:text="@string/good_news_text" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Why did you nest 2 RelativeLayouts? One is enough. The other one is **redundant**. And bad for performances. Just set a dummy View (0dp for both width and height) in the center and align the  2 TextViews one above that and one below it. But the problem remains: how to center the View on the screen? I guess you have to do some math in the Java side.

Comment: have you tried gravity:center ?

Comment: @Rotwang good point on redundant RelativeLayouts. I see the lint warning in AndroidStudio but couldnt come up with the correct way to handle it.  Thank you for advice on how to handle it! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use for example CoordinatorLayout. Elements in this layout has no relation between them so can be one on another.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:id="@+id/root_layout"
>

    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:text="Text not in center">

        </TextView>

    </RelativeLayout>


    <!-- This is centered TextView -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:text="Text in center"
        >

    </TextView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Two important things:

1. Centered TextView should be children of CoordinatorLayout
2. To center in CoordinatorLayout use attribute **android:layout_gravity="center"**
3. If we want exacly center we need to change margin because toolbar size is our not wanted difference for exactly center, i used **android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"** to move TextView up by toolbar height.

> Calculating screen and setting position programically is not good proposition, this can cause not wanted problems when for example user rotates screen.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you! :)

Comment: No problem @LudvigH

Answer (score 0):

You can get the real dimension of you screen by

```
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    displayMetrics.widthPixels; //screen width
    displayMetrics.heightPixels; //screen height
```

then

```
    LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(int width, int height);
    layoutParams.setMargins(int left, int top, int right, int bottom);
    viewToCenter.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```